# Boost.DateTime issue with adding long year durations

Tags: c++, datetime, boost, duration

I get an exception when adding 3000 years to a valid boost::gregorian::date object.

```
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_types.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    boost::gregorian::date d1(1500, 6, 1);
    boost::gregorian::date d2(4500, 6, 1);
    const auto duration = boost::gregorian::years(3000);
    std::cout << d1 << " + " << duration.number_of_years() << "Y\n";
    const auto d3 = d1 + duration;
    std::cout << d3 << "\n";
}
```

I see the first output:

```
1500-Jun-01 + 3000Y
```

but then I get the exception `Year is out of valid range: 1400..10000`. Am I using the duration type wrong? The Boost library version is 1.59. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 (64 bit build).

Comment: Does this happen with a more recent Boost? If yes, you should probably report it as a bug.

Comment: You can find a fix here: https://github.com/boostorg/date_time/pull/41

Comment: Thank you! I guess I will have to upgrade to newer boost.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in Boost::DateTime: https://github.com/boostorg/date_time/pull/41